# How to print a window in pdf file instead of xps file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

when I use the function window.print() to print the content of my html page, It generates me an xps file but I would like it to generate an pdf file.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Interesting. See [What Is an XPS File and Why Does Windows Want Me to Print to One?](https://www.howtogeek.com/148499/what-is-an-xps-file-and-why-does-windows-want-me-to-print-to-one/). Use FOSS

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to generate it, just use  http://pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_input paste your code and you are done!

Comment: Hey @ImmanueNL. From the question, it appears that Dev1996 is asking about the function in Windows to print the content as PDF. Your suggestion does not seem to solve that problem :)

Comment: @ShagunSodhani lol thank you, but it was just an alternative :)